# trying to build my android UI but always having an error when building

Tags: android

Im trying to build my android UI but I got this errors when building.

- Error:(6, 68) cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'AbsoluteLayout'.
- Error:(1, 56) s4s-elt-schema-ns: The namespace of element 'x' must be from the schema namespace, 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'.
- Error:(1, 56) s4s-elt-invalid: Element 'x' is not a valid element in a schema document.
- Error:(1, 56) schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'null', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not .

can anyone help me? :(

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AbsoluteLayout
    android:id="@+id/widget0"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/widget79"
        android:layout_width="307dp"
        android:layout_height="179dp"
        android:layout_x="9dp"
        android:layout_y="249dp">
    <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/widget53"
            android:layout_width="184dp"
            android:layout_height="178dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">
        <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/widget37"
                android:layout_width="182dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn7"
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="7" />
            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn8"
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="8" />
            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn9"
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="9" />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/widget41"
                android:layout_width="181dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn4"
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="4" />
            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn6"
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="6" />
            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn5"
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="5" />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/widget45"
                android:layout_width="181dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn1"
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="1" />
            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn2"
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="2" />
            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn3"
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="3" />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/widget49"
                android:layout_width="182dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn0"
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="0" />
            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnDot"
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="." />
            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnPi"
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="&#928;" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/widget78"
            android:layout_width="123dp"
            android:layout_height="173dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">
        <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/widget68"
                android:layout_width="122dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnDel"
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Del" />
            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnAC"
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="AC" />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/widget69"
                android:layout_width="123dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnTimes"
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="*" />
            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnDiv"
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="/" />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/widget60"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnPlus"
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="+" />
            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnMinus"
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="-" />
        </TableRow>
        <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnEquals"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="=" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtDisplay"
        android:layout_width="316dp"
        android:layout_height="58dp"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:layout_x="2dp"
        android:layout_y="3dp" />
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

and this is my manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="my.calculator"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
<application android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity android:name="Calculator"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: you should not use absolute layout it's deprecated ... use relative layout instead ..

Comment: @Darkie ok sir, ill try

Comment: yes you should try that and then tell me if there is any error ...

Comment: but thats not the problem. Try to set this line as the first declaration inside the AbosluteLayout: xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android". I don´t know if it´s the problem, give it a try

Comment: As already mentioned absolute layout is deprecated, but that's not the reason for your errors. I can run your layout no problem.

Try cleaning your project, if that fails, Can you post your manifest?

Comment: @Darkie still got the same error sir when using Relative layout

Comment: @James ok sir.. wait

Comment: @EdmarAndang I ran your layout it's working properly on my system try cleaning your project ...

Comment: @Darkie Ok sir .. maybe Ill try running it again tomorrow as it is already late in the evening here, thanks for answering my question sir

Comment: no problem ... tell me tomorrow if it worked or not ... :)